# One of three Mongo Shard node is running with very high CPU LOAD/USAGE

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-3.2

We have three mongo shards with db version v3.2.10.The primary shard is running with very high CPU usage ~675% while other 2 shard node are running ~12% CPU usage.

Here is output for $top command of primary shard:

```
    PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
3825494 mongod    20   0 44.4g  37g  10m S 662.5 62.2  14276:02 mongod
   2803 root      20   0  4380   84    0 S  0.3  0.0   71:59.57  rngd
```

output of $top command for secondary shard:

```
    PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND  
2504833 mongod    20   0 38.3g  36g   9m S 10.0 60.9   1686:11 mongod
3891605 qateam    20   0  454m  12m    0 S  2.0  0.0  53:34.66 node_exporte
```

Output of db.currentOp() at shard1 where CPU is high and with more secs_running

---

```
1)
     {
                        "desc" : "rsSync",
                        "threadId" : "140545421088512",
                        "active" : true,
                        "opid" : 76313,
                        "secs_running" : 329997,
                        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong("329997131632"),
                        "op" : "none",
                        "ns" : "local.replset.minvalid",
                        "query" : {

                        },
                        "numYields" : 0,
                        "locks" : {

                        },
                        "waitingForLock" : false,
                        "lockStats" : {
                                "Global" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "r" : NumberLong(72414875),
                                                "w" : NumberLong(54311146),
                                                "R" : NumberLong(18103716),
                                                "W" : NumberLong(18103716)
                                        },
                                        "acquireWaitCount" : {
                                                "R" : NumberLong(132),
                                                "W" : NumberLong(3942872)
                                        },
                                        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                                "R" : NumberLong(18610043),
                                                "W" : NumberLong(1490223084)
                                        }
                                },
                                "Database" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "r" : NumberLong(6),
                                                "w" : NumberLong(1),
                                                "W" : NumberLong(54311145)
                                        },
                                        "acquireWaitCount" : {
                                                "W" : NumberLong(1)
                                        },
                                        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                                "W" : NumberLong(61)
                                        }
                                },
                                "Collection" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "r" : NumberLong(5)
                                        }
                                },
                                "Metadata" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "w" : NumberLong(1)
                                        }
                                },
                                "oplog" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "r" : NumberLong(1),
                                                "w" : NumberLong(1)
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }

2)
{
                        "desc" : "WT RecordStoreThread: local.oplog.rs",
                        "threadId" : "140545378072320",
                        "active" : true,
                        "opid" : 715968754,
                        "secs_running" : 1310,
                        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(1310975777),
                        "op" : "none",
                        "ns" : "local.oplog.rs",
                        "query" : {

                        },
                        "numYields" : 0,
                        "locks" : {

                        },
                        "waitingForLock" : false,
                        "lockStats" : {
                                "Global" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "r" : NumberLong(1),
                                                "w" : NumberLong(1)
                                        }
                                },
                                "Database" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "w" : NumberLong(1)
                                        }
                                },
                                "oplog" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "w" : NumberLong(1)
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
```

How can I control and keep it down to normal CPU usage range.

Answer (score 2):

Because in at normal situation all traffic (read, write) goes to the primary node, it is the busiest node at replica set. Secondaries just replicate changes (update, insert, delete) and not responding to client queries.

But check your I/O. `iostat -mx 1` what are %iowait, %util. `iotop` program shows how much you actually read and write to disk. Do you know how many IOPS your disk system can server? MongoDB is very IOPS centric, if mongod cannot have "enough" IOPS, it is going to be "slow". Especially secondaries can start "lagging" if they cannot write disk fast enough. That you can see from the primary with `rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()` command. Secondaries SHOULD stay under 2 seconds behind.